# js client for azure DirectLine App Service Extension

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat, webchatjs

I am using DirectLine App service extension in order to connect with bot logic. I want to know if there any JS client available for this on the UI side. Azure documentation have C# one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-client?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

but I am looking for a Js client because I want to develop a custom UI. I don't want to use webchat for this.